# Implementing "cat" in Java so that it will output raw bytes to System.out

Tags: java

I am writing a very simple implementation of the `cat` function from unix in Java:

```java
public class Cat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int ch;
            BufferedWriter log = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
            while ((ch = System.in.read()) != -1)
                log.write((char) ch);
            log.flush();
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I pass a text file input like so, I get:

```
$cat hello.txt | java Cat

this is
the second line
no jk the third
```

However when I pass in another kind of file like a jpg, it does not copy properly. I will pass in a jpg, but when I try to open it the error I get is:

```
Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xc3 0xbf)
```

I'm pretty naive when it comes to IO related stuff so I am having trouble figuring out what is going wrong. Am I not writing to standard output like I think I am?

Comment: `System.in.read()` reads *bytes*, not *chars*.

Comment: Ah, ok. That is what I want, I guess the way I am writing to stdout is incorrect though. Is there a way to read a given file's bytes and output the same exact bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got confused between `byte` and `char`, and the respective classes used to read and write them (which is easy to do when you are new to Java IO):

- `byte` is a single byte (8 bits). You read them using an `InputStream`, and write them using an `OutputStream`.
- `char` is a two-byte unsigned int (16 bits). You read them using a `Reader` and write them using a `Writer`.

`System.in` is an `InputStream`, so you are actually reading a `byte` from it, not a `char`; the only reason `System.in.read()` returns `int` is so that it can indicate that no bytes were available to read.

As such, the following should work:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = System.in.read ()) != -1)
  System.out.write(ch);
System.out.flush(); // Optional, it will flush upon JVM termination anyway.
```

Note that JPEGs are composed of `byte`s, not `char`s. As such, if you use classes for writing `char`s to write the contents of the JPEG file, the contents will likely be garbage.

Comment: just to clarify this would encompass all different types of inputs right? in other words does the code you provided read in the bytes of the file and writes the bytes of the file, regardless of the file type?

Comment: This just treats all files as a stream of bytes, so it should work for any file.

Comment: One nit picked: I would suggest `int byt` as more mnemonic than `int ch` for a value that we all agree is not a char.